# Quirky behavior of pandas.DataFrame.equals

Tags: python, pandas

I have noticed a quirky thing. Let's say A and B are dataframe.

A is:

```
A
   a  b  c
0  x  1  a
1  y  2  b
2  z  3  c
3  w  4  d
```

B is:

```
B
   a  b  c
0  1  x  a
1  2  y  b
2  3  z  c
3  4  w  d
```

As we can see above, the elements under column `a` in `A` and `B` are different, but `A.equals(B)` yields `True`

`A==B` correctly shows that the elements are not equal:

```
A==B
       a      b     c
0  False  False  True
1  False  False  True
2  False  False  True
3  False  False  True
```

**Question**: Can someone please explain why `.equals()` yields `True`? Also, I researched this topic on SO. As per [contract of pandas.DataFrame.equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552116/contract-of-pandas-dataframe-equals), `Pandas` must return `False`. I'd appreciate any help.

I am a beginner, so I'd appreciate any help.

---

Here's `json` format and `._data` of A and B

**A**

```
`A.to_json()`
Out[114]: '{"a":{"0":"x","1":"y","2":"z","3":"w"},"b":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4},"c":{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c","3":"d"}}'
```

and `A._data` is

```
BlockManager
Items: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
IntBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 4, dtype: int64
ObjectBlock: slice(0, 4, 2), 2 x 4, dtype: object
```

**B**

B's json format:

```
B.to_json()
'{"a":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4},"b":{"0":"x","1":"y","2":"z","3":"w"},"c":{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c","3":"d"}}'


B._data
BlockManager
Items: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
IntBlock: slice(0, 1, 1), 1 x 4, dtype: int64
ObjectBlock: slice(1, 3, 1), 2 x 4, dtype: object
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212697/confirming-equality-of-two-pandas-dataframes/38213972#38213972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the answer you linked in your question, essentially the behaviour of `pandas.DataFrame.equals` mimics [`numpy.array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html).
The docs for `np.array_equal` state that it returns:

> True if two arrays have the same shape and elements, False otherwise.

Which your 2 dataframes satisfies.

Comment: Thanks sacul. I checked docs at `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html`. All I could find is that `Determines if two NDFrame objects contain the same elements. NaNs in the same location are considered equal.` Could you please point me to the right direction? Also, what's the best way to check for the equality?

Comment: @watchtower it is: `(A==B).all().all()`

Comment: You can also check out the docs I linked to `numpy.array_equal`, which explains it differently, but is essentially the same function. As for how to check equality, @U9-Forward's comment makes sense (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to sacul and U9-Forward's answers, I've done some further analysis and it looks like the reason you are seeing `True` and not `False` as you expected might have something more to do with this line of the [docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html):

> This function requires that the elements have the same dtype as their respective elements in the other Series or DataFrame.

[image: dataframes]

With the above dataframes, when I run `df.equals()`, this is what is returned:

```
>>> A.equals(B)
Out: True
>>> B.equals(C)
Out: False
```

These two align with what the other answers are saying, `A` and `B` are the same shape and have the same elements, so they are the same. While `B` and `C` have the same shape, but different elements, so they aren't the same.

On the other hand:

```
>>> A.equals(D)
Out: False
```

Here `A` and `D` have the same shape, and the same elements. But still they are returning false. The difference between this case and the one above is that all of the `dtypes` in the comparison match up, as it says the above docs quote. `A` and `D` both have the `dtypes`: str, int, str.

Comment: For further clarity: I am saying that the comparison of A and B should return False, but the function is not working correctly because it needs to compare like with like `dtypes`, so it is erroneously returning True. A and D have matching dtypes: str, int, str - so their comparison is working correctly and returning False (as the two string columns are switched)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html):

> Determines if two NDFrame objects contain the same elements. NaNs in the same location are considered equal.

**Determines if two NDFrame objects contain the same elements**!!!

**ELEMNTS** not including **COLUMNS**

So that's why returns `True`

If you want it to return false and check the columns do:

```
print((A==B).all().all())
```

Output:

```
False
```